# how do you css style a scroll bar in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, listview, javafx

Is it possible to set the corner of a listview to a specific color or to hide it/make it transparent and if so you how would I do that?

Below are my current attempts to style the listview using css.

```css
.list-view .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-background-color:#2c365d;
}

.list-view .increment-button ,.list-view .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
    -fx-border-color:transparent;
}

.list-view .scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color:#455491;
    -fx-background-insets: 5, 5, 5;
    -fx-background-radius: 5;
}

.list-view .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-scale-x: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can style the corner of your scroll pane like this:

```
.scroll-bar > .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: #2c365d ;
}
```

I highly recommend Scene Builder and its CSS Analyzer, is great for looking up things like this. Using the CSS Analyzer you can view the "Styleable path" and find the .corner style class, as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Even if you create your GUI in code, you could still use Scene Builder to simply look up things like this and create quick mock-ups.

**EDIT:**
Though the above answer is fine for `Scroll Panes`, it's not the exact same for a `ListView` which is what op wanted - my bad. The `ListView` have the styleable path:

> .list-view .virtual-flow .corner

So this should work to style a corner of a list-view.

```
.virtual-flow > .corner {    
    -fx-background-color: #2c365d ;
}
```

I'm assuming that you will only have one of those `ListView` and then you could give it an id and only style the corners of your specific `ListView`.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work in my case, I probably should have been more specific as well in that I am using a list-view as that could potentially change the answer, however, I will take a look at the CSS analyzer

Comment: You could try to give the listview an ID or style class and change the css to something like #myListView .corner{ -fx-background-color: #2c365d;}. I might have been a bit too fast when looking at your issue. What that will do is to style any children, on any level, that is underneath of your #myListView node.

Comment: I'll see if I can have a look at this later today unless someone else answers by then, but the reason why I used the >  was so that the css would only be applied to the children with the .corner style class that are direct descendants of the scroll-bar

Comment: yeah, that works perfectly after the edit, much appreciated !!

Comment: I have created the CSS class and in scenebuilder I used the css as stylesheet. I want to change scrollbar and the buttons. How do I tell that to the controller or whereever I need to call that? the changes I made did not affect my programm...

Comment: I suggest that you create your own question, it's difficult to answer what might be wrong based on the information you've provided.

Comment: "I highly recommend Scene Builder and its CSS Analyzer" - without a doubt the best tool for understanding JavaFX CSS, thanks for the tip - saves Google search after Google search for finding out the correct CSS to edit.